# How to extract specific rows from a sheet in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet with a number of columns. One of them lists different dates in a format of ''Planned dd/mm/yyyy''. The dates range from 2003 until 2011. I only need those from 2010 and 2011. 
What I want to do is to find the values with 2010 and 2011 in that column and copy paste them along with the respective rows to another sheet. 
I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you able to sort the sheet by this column? Although, since it looks like a text field (combined text and date) this might not work to sort in order of date?

Comment: I can remove the 'planned' using the find/replace function and change the entire column into a date format. If you have a solution for how to take it from there...

Answer (score 2):

Once you have removed "Planned " from the data and changed the column into date format (as per your comment) then you can select all the rows in the sheet and choose Data > Sort from the menu to sort the sheet by the date column (make sure "No Header Row" is selected). It should then be easy enough to select all rows in 2010/2011, since they are now contiguous, and copy them to another sheet.